# How can I force Firefox to open a aspx file?

Tags: firefox, file-format

http://www.morningstar.es/Default.aspx asks for a file operation (open with xxx app or safe), http://clerk.house.gov/floorsummary/floor.aspx, however opens without a hitch (as in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1815428)).

Any suggestions? I don't have [silverlight](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94230/open-aspx-extension-website-on-ubuntu) installed.

Comment: I think that site is mis-configured. If you search for it on Google, you can view a cached copy. Curiously, the cached copy still wants to load something called 'RegistrationPopup.aspx.' If you are really determined to continue, see this Stackoverflow question on converting .aspx files to PDFs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220423/directly-convert-aspx-to-pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just viewed those sites in Firefox 10 on Ubuntu 11.10 and they display correctly. For Silverlight you can install Moonlight, it's the Linux equivalent. A webpage ending in ASPX has to be hosted on an IIS windows server, meaning you won't be able to save an ASPX page to file and do *right-click>open with Firefox*. That being said, I tried browsing those sites and following a few links, everything seemed to be fine. Make sure you run the latest software, I've found that a lot of bugs in Firefox 9 have been cleared out by using Firefox 10.

Comment: +1 good to know. I've never seen that dialogue from a site before.

Comment: One _possibility_ is that a site was browser-sniffing and didn't recognize the user agent string. That problem should not occur with Fx 10 (from Ubuntu) but existed with Fx 8 and 9. The relevant bug is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/897794).

Comment: No problem with Fx10.